# Drop down button in flutter not switching values to the selected value

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've recently started programming using dart and flutter and everything has been going smoothly for my app, although recently i wanted to add drop down menu to provide the user with multiple options to pick from. everything worked as planned however when i pick a value from the list it doesn't change the value in the box, it goes back to the hint or an empty box. any help would be appreciated!

here is my code for the dropdownbutton:

```
Widget buildDropdownButton() {
String newValue;

return new Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
  child: new Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      new ListTile(
        title: const Text('Frosting'),
        trailing: new DropdownButton<String>(
            hint: Text('Choose'),
            onChanged: (String changedValue) {
              newValue=changedValue;
              setState(() {
                newValue;
                print(newValue);
              });
            },
            value: newValue,
            items: <String>['None', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'ButterCream']
                .map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text(value),
              );
            }).toList()),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: could you put your stateful widget?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The error is because you are declaring a method variable `newValue` you must declare that  variable as global inside your `StatefulWidget`.

```
   String newValue;

  Widget buildDropdownButton() {
  return new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          title: const Text('Frosting'),
          trailing: new DropdownButton<String>(
              hint: Text('Choose'),
              onChanged: (String changedValue) {
                newValue=changedValue;
                setState(() {
                  newValue;
                  print(newValue);
                });
              },
              value: newValue,
              items: <String>['None', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'ButterCream']
                  .map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList()),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
  }
```

Comment: Hello! I want to ask you, why can't we declare a variable inside the method? Why should we declare a variable globally?

Comment: @datafile4 because that global value gonna be kept if you change. If you define it locally then its value gonna be null if you return your widget out

Answer (score 15):

Faced same issue and none of the answers worked. Then, I found the solution in one of my old projects.

I was using it in a `AlertDialog` here.

So, Change `DropdownButton` to `DropdownButtonFormField`

and add `onSaved` exactly as `onChanged`:

```
onSaved: (value) {
    setState(() {
        _selectedValue = value;
    });
}
```

That's it. It will start working.

Comment: This the only solution worked for me, thanks Lalit, it did work after changing DropdownButton to DropdownButtonFormField even with onChange

Comment: This was the solution for me. In my case the `DropdownButton` was inside a `FutureBuilder`, and its `value` was initialized using the future fetched value. The reason why the DropdownButtonFormField wasn't changing was because every time I called `setState` from inside `DropdownButton.onChanged`, it was rebuilding the entire widget, fetching the old value again.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.

Comment: But why Onchanged is not working with us?

Comment: You can set `onClick` in the `DropDownMenuItem` and update the value there.

Comment: In my scenario, dropdown is just a field in a dialogue I need to collect some info, but setting a state is not looks good as it will re build whole widget state, which have many other things as well. Switching from DropdownButton to DropdownButtonFormField works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

wrap dropdown button with StatefulBuilder and initialise **newValue** outside build method.

```
  StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Change Status"),
            content: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text('Choose'),
                    onChanged: (String changedValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        newValue = changedValue;
                        print(newValue);
                      });
                    },
                    value: newValue,
                    items: <String>[
                      'None',
                      'Chocolate',
                      'Vanilla',
                      'ButterCream'
                    ].map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList()),
              ),
            ),
            
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem although I was already using the solution above.

for anyone who has this problem and the above solution does not work, try separating FutureBuilder from the dropdown. this is how your final code should look like:

```
class TheFuture extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture(),
      builder: (ctx, snp) {
        if (!snp.hasData) return LoadingLine();
        return TheBuilder(snp.data);
      },
    );
  }
}

class TheBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const TheBuilder(this.mp);
  final Map<String, dynamic> mp;
  @override
  _MessageUSScreenFilterBodyState createState() =>
      _MessageUSScreenFilterBodyState();
}

class _MessageUSScreenFilterBodyState extends State<MessageUSScreenFilterBody> {
  int _selectedId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      selectedItemBuilder: (context) =>
          widget.mp['myData'].map((e) => Text(e.type)).toList(),
      items: widget.mp['myData']
          .map(
            (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(e.type),
              value: e.id,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      value: _selectedId,
      onChanged: (int _id) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedId = _id;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```