# Dropdown selection not displaying with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, dropdown

I' m gettings items from JSON and displaying them in a dropdown. When the person select an item from the dropdown list, I get the selection but the selected item doesn't change.

For example we have (tokyo, paris, new york) in the list. By default selection is tokyo. When the person select paris, I get it but the selection doesn't change in the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
new DropdownButton(
  value: cities.elementAt(0),
  hint: new Text("Ville"),
  items: cities.map((String value) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem(
      value: value,
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(
            Icons.location_city,
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),
          new Text(value)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (String value) {
    getTravelCity(value);
  },
),
```

When the person select an item, it still showing the default value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735906/drop-down-button-in-flutter-not-switching-values-to-the-selected-value?rq=1

Comment: i tried it but still have the same problem

Answer (score 26):

Make sure you are not declaring the selectedValue inside the Widget the below example works for me perfectly.

[image]

here is the working code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/7818b6ff4109fe3008309fbda7fc1e34) to test it out

```
var currentSelectedValue;
const deviceTypes = ["Mac", "Windows", "Mobile"];

 Widget typeFieldWidget() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: FormField<String>(
        builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: Text("Select Device"),
                value: currentSelectedValue,
                isDense: true,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                  });
                  print(currentSelectedValue);
                },
                items: deviceTypes.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### Alternate Solution

In case you are using DropDownButton in a stateless widget, You can rebuild dropDown Widget by wrapping it in ValueListenableBuilder.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String? currentSelectedValue;

   final ValueNotifier<List<String>> _listNotifier =
      ValueNotifier<List<String>>(["Mac", "Windows", "Mobile"]);

  Widget typeFieldWidget() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _listNotifier,
      builder: (BuildContext context, List<String> list, Widget? child) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: FormField<String>(
            builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
              return InputDecorator(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text("Select Device"),
                    value: currentSelectedValue,
                    isDense: true,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                        currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                      _listNotifier.notifyListeners();
                    },
                    items: list.map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: typeFieldWidget(),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: that works if you use `SetState` for my case I need a `StatelessWidget`

Comment: thats not possible to render new content on screen without doing a setState thats how flutter works,it needs to redraw the widgets by doing setState,you  may change the variable values in memory but to present with updated value on the screen you need to redraw the ui by calling setState;

Comment: so basically, if I also need to add a new element on my `ListView` I'd also have to do the same: move the `StatelessWidget` to `Stateful` and change the state only for that page

Comment: if you tried the above code it will work,if you want to add new element simply add that element to your list e.g ```deviceTypes``` in above code,so that the new element gets reflected in the drop down,whenever the drop down list is rendered on screen it fetches the newlist.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the dartpad link of the working code please check it

Comment: I came again after a while to the same error. This time I was using a `ShowDialog` and for this you need to use `StatefulBuilder` despite you already have a `Stateful` widget: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19343

Comment: Most important gotcha: "Make sure you are not declaring the selectedValue inside the Widget"!

Comment: @Dani I have updated the answer, which allows you to use the DropdownButton in a stateless widget.

Answer (score 11):

```
This is the solution: "StatefulBuilder()"

       Future<void> AgregarContacto() async {
             String dropdownValue = 'Exento';
             return showDialog<void>(
           context: context,
           barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
           builder: (BuildContext context) {
                 return StatefulBuilder(
                   builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                   return AlertDialog(
                   title: Text('Agregar cliente', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                   content:
                     SingleChildScrollView(
                       child: ListBody(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Center(
                             child: Material(
                               type: MaterialType.transparency,
                               child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                 items: <String>[
                                   'Responsable inscripto',
                                   'Monotributista',
                                   'Exento',
                                   'Consumidor final',
                                   'No responsable'
                                 ]
                                     .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((
                                     String value) {
                                   return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                     value: value,
                                     child: Text(value),
                                   ); //DropMenuItem
                                 }).toList(),
                                 value: dropdownValue,
                                 onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                   setState(() {
                                     dropdownValue = newValue;
                                     print("new${newValue}");
                                   }); //setState
                                 },
                                 //OnChange
                                 isExpanded: false,
                                 hint: Text('Responsable inscripto',
                                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                               ),
                             ), //Material
                           ), //Center
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   actions: <Widget>[
                         FlatButton(
                           child: Text('Regret'),
                           onPressed: () {
                             Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                       ),
                    ],
                 );
            }
            );
           },
         );
       }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have a very long stateless screen and wanted to have only one dropdown in that stateful. This post just gave me that. cheers. I tested it and it works like charm.

Answer (score 4):

this was a bug reported in the [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6352) of Flutter.

The correct implementions is:

```dart
class _DropdownButtonBugState extends State<DropdownButtonBug> {

  final List<String> _items = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'].toList();

  String _selection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selection = _items.first;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dropdownMenuOptions = _items
      .map((String item) =>
        new DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: new Text(item))
      )
      .toList();

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _selection,
        items: dropdownMenuOptions,
        onChanged: (s) {
          setState(() {
            _selection = s;
          });
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Dropdown Button can be wrapped inside a StatefulBuilder() widget if the selected values are not updated after the selction.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this problem in future. Use variable to set the value to DropdownButton and when the onChanged called update the variable using setState

```
Expanded(child: DropdownButton<String>(
          items: cities.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          value: city,
          onChanged: (String val) {
            _onDropDownChanged(val);
          },
        ),)
```

update the city variable by using state

```
void _onDropDownChanged(String val) {
    setState(() {
      this.city = val;
    });
  }
```

For further information check the link below

https://github.com/FazalHussain/Flutter-Demo/blob/trip_cost_app/lib/main.dart

Comment: This woked for me. until I used this

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to update the "value: " parameter with "setState(() {});" method and the new value must be of the same type of the one passed to "onChanged:". I suggest tho do this because your are able to change dynamically your icon.

1) declare a new class in the top of the file;

```
class city {
  final String name;
  final IconData icon;

  const city({
    this.name,
    this.icon,
  });
}
```

2) the add this in the state of your widget:

```
class yourState extend<myWidget>{

List<city> cities = [
    new city(name: "tokio", icon: Icons.location_city),
    new city(name: "paris", icon: Icons.location_city),
    new city(name: "new york", icon: Icons.location_city),
  ];

int index = 0;

Widget drop() {
    return DropdownButton(
        value: cities[index],
        hint: new Text("Ville"),
        items: cities.map((city value) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem(
            value: value,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Icon(
                  value.icon,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
                new Text(value.name)
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (city value) {
          setState(() {
            index = cities.indexOf(value);
            print(index);
          });
          //getTravelCity(value.name);
        });
  }

}
```

now call "drop()" where you want your DropDown. Bye!!

Comment: The `value` property of `DropdownButton`has been updated I think. Now rather than assigning the actual `String Value`, you can just use index instead

Answer (score 0):

Is used this code in my most recent app and it works. Maybe you could compare it to your code.

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
    items: _persons.map((String val) {
      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: val,
        child: new Container(
          child: new Card(
            child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Icon(Icons.person),
              new Text(val),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
    hint: new Card(
        child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
      new Icon(Icons.person),
      new Text("check"),
    ])),
    value: _selectedPerson,
    onChanged: (newVal) {
      _selectedPerson = newVal;
      setState(() {});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You hard-coded the first city as **value** for the dropdown.

```
new DropdownButton(
            value: cities.elementAt(0), //this one
...
```

You need to have some `state` variable to hold the selected city.

```
class YourStatefulWidgetState extends State<YourStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  initState() {
   super.initState();
   selectedCity = cities.elementAt(0)
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
   new DropdownButton(
            value: selectedCity,
            hint: new Text("Ville"),
            items: cities.map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem(value: value,
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Icon(
                      Icons.location_city, color: Colors.deepOrange,),
                    new Text(value)
                  ],
                ),);
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedCity = getTravelCity(value);
              });
            },),
     ...
```

Comment: i forget to tell you that the dropdown is in an AlertDialog

Comment: @PondikpaTchabao Do you have your own dialog widget? I think this code does not work in your case, because `setState` call is updating the widget that built the dialog, not the dialog. You should create your own 'DropdownAlertDialog' `Stateful` widget

Answer (score 0):

I tired all the options, including all the flutter issues.
But after 2 hours of search. I found my solution for my Bloc implemented widget.

```
 onChanged: (Object value) {
     selectedCity = getTravelCity(value);
     setState((){}; });
        );
```

You can feel the difference here. Since I'm populating the list under BlocBuilder with some state, It won't allow you to rebuild the dropdown menu. So after setting the dropdownValue then call the setState method. It will allow you to reflect the value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make a variable as the default value of your dropdownmenu value, then in your `onChanged`, variable = value; and do a setstate.