# Flutter DropDownButton

Tags: flutter

I try to display categories data in `dropdownbutton`, when I choose `category` I get this error,

```
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
```

code `DropDownButton`:

```
    class _DropDownButtonState extends State<DropDownButton> {
  final CollectionReference categoryData = Firestore.instance
      .collection('category')
      .document('house')
      .collection('subCategory');
  Stream<List<Categories>> categories;
  Categories _currentCategory;
  @override
  void initState() {
    categories = categoriesData;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Categories>>(
        stream: categories,
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return DropdownButton(
            hint: Text('choose category'),
            value: _currentCategory,
            items: snapshot.data
                .map((doc) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(doc.categoryname),
                      value: doc,
                    ))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (doc) => setState(() {
              _currentCategory = doc;
              print(_currentCategory.categoryname);
            }),
          );
        }));
  }

  Future createHouseCategory(_categorynameController) async {
    var id = Uuid();
    String categoryId = id.v1();
    await categoryData
        .document(categoryId)
        .setData({'categoryname': _categorynameController});
  }

  List<Categories> _categoriesDataFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Categories(
        categoryname: doc.data['categoryname'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Categories>> get categoriesData {
    return categoryData.snapshots().map(_categoriesDataFromSnapshot);
  }


}
```

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: What do you mean? when i try to select category, after i get error Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:803:15
items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
return item.value == value;
}).length == 1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Categories'. \nEither
zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this link where I have solved the question for the dropdown :

[Dropdown Button wont change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350543/dropdown-button-wont-change/60352134#60352134)

maybe you are not giving the desired parameters to the value Field, that's why it is not getting the index to show in the dropdown button. let me know if it works.

If you have any issue just give me the JSON sample, maybe we can work on it

Comment: I added void initState and solved it. See my post i edited. Can you tell me this is a good way?

Comment: Actually I am not sure but according to this link: https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-use-streambuilder-to-populate-dropdownbutton-in-flutter/, the way you have written is a good way.