# Flutter - How to select DropdownButton item in widget test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-dropdownbutton

I tried selecting a `DropdownButton item` like this:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_test_sample/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Select Dropdown item test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const SampleApp());

    final dropdown = find.byKey(const ValueKey('dropdown'));

    await tester.tap(dropdown);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final dropdownItem = find.byKey(const ValueKey('First item key'));

    await tester.tap(dropdownItem);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
}
```

But unfortunately, It throws this exception:
[image]

There seems to be something that keeps creating an identical `DropdownButton item` with the same key, thereby making the widget test fail because, `tester.tap()` cannot "tap" on two widgets at the same time.

Here's the full implementation of the `DropdownButton` widget:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const SampleApp());
}

class SampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dropdown Test Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DummyDropdown(
          key: ValueKey('dropdown'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DummyDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const DummyDropdown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DummyDropdown> createState() => _DummyDropdownState();
}

class _DummyDropdownState extends State<DummyDropdown> {
  String? text = 'Dropdown';
  String? textValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: textValue,
      underline: Container(),
      dropdownColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      hint: Text(
        text!,
      ),
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(
          () {
            textValue = newValue;
            text = newValue;
          },
        );
      },
      items: <String>['First item', 'Second item', 'Third item']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
        (value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            key: ValueKey('$value key'),
            child: Text(
              value,
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Widget testing in drop down button is different than other widgets please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490039/flutter-widget-test-does-not-trigger-dropdownbutton-onchanged-when-selecting-ano) for more. In this is case select the last element from the text "First Item".This will work.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
    
    import 'package:testapp/main.dart';
    
    void main() {
  testWidgets('Select Dropdown item test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const SampleApp());

    final dropdown = find.byKey(const ValueKey('dropdown'));

    await tester.tap(dropdown);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    ///if you want to tap first item
    final dropdownItem = find.text('First item').last;

    await tester.tap(dropdownItem);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });

}
```

The issue is here. when we tap the drop down one was already selected and other one is not selected. So you can test that item using the text value.

```
final dropdownItem = find.text('First item').last;
```

Comment: What if the dropdown contains dynamic values?